# Link non-unique, non-primary-keys as foreign-key relationship

Tags: sql

i have two table first one called religion and it has this columns (code , English name , description )

this the record on it
code    ename
20  Chirstian 
30  Jwiesh
40  Other
50  Buddhist
60  Coptic
70  Hindo
UN  Unknown

the second table called person and one of its columns is "religion" , the religion on person table is the code of religion

here i want to link "code" with "religion" in table person , and both of them are not unique , how could i link them?

Comment: yes and it give an error: the columns in table ' xyz' do not match an existing primary key or unique constraint

Comment: i really have to link them , because one of them has code and description of code and the other table just has the code , so i want to link the two code so i can know the meaning of those code

Comment: You don't need a foreign-key relationship if you want to join two tables.

Comment: Probably you should change your table structures

Answer (score 0):

If you need to match them and they are not unique, you can create a join table between your both tables (like: joinTable(id_tab1 int, id_tab2 int)) with a clustered primary key over both id columns.

Due to the lack of given information (like table structures etc.) I have to guess what you really try.

I thought about a structure like this:

**Tab1**

```
ID (PK)
... some other columns ...
```

**Tab2**

```
ID (PK)
... some other columns ...
```

Multiple rows of Tab1 can link to a row of Tab2 and multiple Tows of Tab2 can also link to one row in Tab1 (M:N cardinality).

In this case my suggestion above would look like this:

**JoinTab**

```
ID_Tab1 (PK) (FK-> to Tab1)
ID_Tab2 (PK) (FK-> to Tab2)
```

The PK is clustered, which will prevent duplicates.

Hopefully I've get your question right and it would help you.

Comment: i can't understand why should use join table ? and what will be the benefit from it?

Comment: Thank you. I'll take  a look at it later then. Maybe I need to update my answer afterwards.